Title: Lulu Print API: Validation Errors for Single Page Cover PDF
I'm having trouble with the Lulu Print API while trying to upload a cover PDF for a book. I have selected the pod_package_id: 0850X0850FCPRECW080CW444GXX for a hardcover book, and I'm encountering the following issues:

Single Page Cover PDF Validation: When I attempt to validate a single-page cover PDF, I receive the following error:
{
    "id": 357353,
    "source_url": "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/a02ub63152c6dtqkc8lob/lulu-square-hardcover-template.pdf?rlkey=imh4eovxttrjrox282fx5rzgl&st=3itmycga&dl=1",
    "errors": [
        "Page Count: We found 1 pages in your PDF. For the book design you selected, the page range must be between 2 and 800 pages. Please update your PDF or select a different book design."
    ],
    "status": "ERROR"
}



Cover PDF Dimensions and Page Count Error: Even when I create a cover PDF with two pages, the order is rejected with the following message:
{
    "printable_normalization": {
        "cover": [
            "Book Size: Your PDF dimensions are 8.500\" x 8.500\" (215.90mm x 215.90mm)For the book size you selected, the PDF dimensions need to be within 18.938\"-19.062\" x 10.188\"-10.312\". (481.01mm-484.19mm x 258.76mm-261.94mm). Please update your PDF dimensions or select a different book size.",
            "Page Count: We found more than 1 page in your file. For a cover file, you must upload a PDF with a single page for the front, spine, and back cover."
        ]
    },
    "source_url": "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/a02ub63152c6dtqkc8lob/lulu-square-hardcover-template.pdf?rlkey=imh4eovxttrjrox282fx5rzgl&st=3itmycga&dl=1",
    "pod_package_id": "0850X0850FCPRECW080CW444GXX",
    "interior_page_count": 24
}



My PDF details:

Template Used: Lulu Square Hardcover Template

Cover Dimensions: 8.500" x 8.500" (215.90mm x 215.90mm)

Interior Page Count: 24


Questions:

Why am I receiving an error about the page count for a single-page cover PDF? The template clearly shows a single page for the cover design.

What are the correct dimensions for the cover PDF for the pod_package_id 0850X0850FCPRECW080CW444GXX? How can I ensure the dimensions are within the acceptable range?

Should the cover PDF be a single page or two pages, considering the error message about page count?
Note: I am creating a pdf with npm package JSPDF


Any guidance on how to resolve these issues and successfully upload the cover PDF would be greatly appreciated


